# Mockito Spring Test Fails When Run as a Gradlew Task

Tags: java, spring, mockito, integration-testing, gradlew

I have the following class to test a job of my spring application.

This job updates the state of an order object resorting to an external API.

When I just run the class the test is successful but when I run as part of a gradlew task (that run multiple integration tests, including this one) it fails with:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
client.updateOrder(
    "o11111",
    <Pending order update integration test$$ lambda$ 3 9 9/ 1 6 3 9 3 4 9 4 3 5>
);
-> at OrderUpdateIntegrationTest.shouldSendPendingOrderUpdatesSubmittedOrders(OrderUpdateIntegrationTest.java:77)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = TestConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(value = {SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@DirtiesContext
public class OrderUpdateIntegrationTest {

  private static final String ORDER_ID_1 = "o11111";
  private static final String ORDER_ID_2 = "o22222";
  static VerificationWithTimeout FIVE_SECOND_TIMEOUT = timeout(SECONDS.toMillis(5));

  @Autowired
  private TestScheduleConfigurer testScheduleConfigurer;

  @MockBean
  private OrdersClient client;
  @MockBean
  private UpdatePendingOrdersTasklet updateOrderAndSendEmail;
  @MockBean
  private UrlBuilder urlBuilder;

  @Mock
  private ResponseEntity<Order> mock200HttpResponse;
  @Mock
  private ResponseEntity<String> mockEmail200HttpResponse;

  private Order order11111;
  private Order order22222;
  private OrderList ordersList = new OrderList();

  @Test
  public void shouldSendPendingOrderUpdatesSubmittedOrders() throws Exception {
    order11111 = buildOrder(ORDER_ID_1);
    order22222 = buildOrder(ORDER_ID_2);
    ordersList.setItems(Arrays.asList(order11111, order22222));

    when(client.getPendingOrdersObject(anyString())).thenReturn(ordersList);
    when(client.updateOrder(any(String.class), any(Order.class))).thenReturn(mock200HttpResponse);
    when(mock200HttpResponse.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
    when(updateOrderAndSendEmail.postSendEmail(any(JSONObject.class))).thenReturn(mockEmail200HttpResponse);
    when(mockEmail200HttpResponse.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);

    testScheduleConfigurer.triggerPendingOrderUpdateSchedule();

    verify(client, FIVE_SECOND_TIMEOUT).updateOrder(eq(ORDER_ID_1), argThat(argument -> argument.getState().equals(OrderState.PROCESSING)));
    verify(client, FIVE_SECOND_TIMEOUT).updateOrder(eq(ORDER_ID_2), argThat(argument -> argument.getState().equals(OrderState.PROCESSING)));
    verify(urlBuilder, times(2)).buildComponent("emailNotifications");
  }

  private Order buildOrder(String orderId) {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setId(orderId);
    order.setSiteId("testSite");
    order.setState(OrderState.SUBMITTED);
    order.setLastModifiedDate("2019-10-20T01:02:03.004Z");

    OrderShippingGroup shippingGroup = new OrderShippingGroup();

    OrderAddress emailAddress = new OrderAddress();
    emailaddress.setemail("test@test.test");
    emailAddress.setFirstName("First Name");
    emailAddress.setLastName("Last Name");

    shippingGroup.setShippingAddress(emailAddress);

    order.setShippingGroups(Arrays.asList(shippingGroup));

    return order;
  }
}
```

I think that the problem is, when I just run the test the `@MockBean` tag creates a new instance of `OrdersClient` to the context, so when a `when()` or `verify()` method is called, it works as expected but if the integration test is executed as a gradlew task, the job might be using a different instance than the one declared as `@MockBean`.

Is there a way to use the same instance for the two scenarios? If this assumption is correct.
If not, what is wrong?

Thank you,
Pedro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateOrder` method was missing multiple mockups so it file with different application configurations.